Como puedo obtener el PLAYER_ID al suscribir a un usuario a ONESIGNAL?
Estoy integrando el servicio de notificaciones PUSH OneSignal a mi proyecto en Laravel. Tengo el OneSignalSDKWorker en la ruta raíz del proyecto, y en el archivo welcome.blade.php tengo el siguiente código
    <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.page.js" defer></script>
    <script>
    window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
    OneSignalDeferred.push(async function(OneSignal) {
        await OneSignal.init({
        appId: "4fe757b1-0e46-4e09-ba50-5b4e58d267b8",
        });
        console.log("Se ejecutó OneSignal")
        console.log(OneSignal.User.PushSubscription.id); //Esto saldrá para usuarios SUSCRITOS.

La línea console.log(OneSignal.User.PushSubscription.id);  me retorna bien el ID del usuario suscrito CUANDO EL USUARIO YA ESTA SUSCRITO, pero yo quiero que cuando el usuario NO está suscrito y le da permisos al navegador, al darle permisos al navegador se capture el subscription_id para poder enviarlo a mi base de datos mysql. Eso es al abrir el sistema en la página welcome.blade.php.
Pero no sé si eso lo debo hacer en este mismo archivo welcome.blade.php o lo tengo que hacer en un archivo aparte. Es que apenas abro el welcome.blade.php se ejecuta todo el script, incluyendo las líneas que he colocado para intentar capturar el ID del usuario. En el momento en que abro el sistema en la página welcome.blade.php el usuario NO ESTÁ SUSCRITO (y es por eso que el navegador le pide permisos para suscribirse), así que es de esperar que OneSignal.User.PushSubscription.id diga undefined.
Quiero escuchar el evento de cuando el usuario le dé clic al botón de suscribirse y en ese preciso momento quiero capturar el suscription_id del usuario que se acaba de crear para poder almacenarlo en mi base de datos mysql.
Estoy usando la API V16. ¿Alguien aquí lo ha hecho con esa versión de la API? ¿Alguien me puede decir si lo estoy haciendo bien o qué estoy haciendo mal?
Intenté hacerlo con la siguiente función sobre mi archivo welcome.blade.php
OneSignal.push(function() {
           OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled().then(function(isEnabled) {
               if (!isEnabled) {
                   // Si las notificaciones no están habilitadas, muestra el prompt
                   OneSignal.showSlidedownPrompt();
               }

               // Escucha el evento de cambio de suscripción
               OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function(isSubscribed) {
                   if (isSubscribed) {
                       // Cuando el usuario se suscribe, obtén el UserId
                       OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
                           if (userId) {
                               console.log("Player ID:", userId);
                           }
                       });
                   }
               });
           });
       });
   ```
   
   pero la consola decía que OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled is not a function.
   tambien dice que OneSignal.on is not a function. 
   


